# JPA PESSIMISTIC_READ does not time out in the specified period

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot, Spring Data, JPA(Hibernate) and MySQL in my project. Here is a method signature from my repository interface:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
@QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "5000") })
@Query("select b from book b where b.id = :bookId")
Optional<Book> findBookCustom(Long bookId);
```

When I inspect the SQL logs, I can see that "for shared" clause is appended to the select statement.

This is a quote from MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) regarding shared locks:

> If any of these rows were changed by another transaction that has not yet committed, your query waits until that transaction ends and then uses the latest values.

I can actually trigger the blocking behaviour by updating the book from another thread. When I suspend the updating thread (after book is updated) and then start the reading thread, I can see that the reading thread is blocked. The problem is that the reading thread waits for about 50 seconds (this is the default wait value, I suppose) until the timeout exception is thrown. The value 5000 I provide in QueryHint does not take effect. I also tried using the EntityManager directly to issue the JPQL select statement, but the result was same. Any ideas on how i can set the timeout to 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we check your MySQL setting via workbench or cmd-line:

```
select @@innodb_lock_wait_timeout
```

Then try to set it to a new value by:

```
set session innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5
```

You could now acquire a pessimistic lock through JPA query, and it will set **LockTimeout** to **5 seconds**. For more information check [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout).

Depending on the persistence provider and database in use, the hint may or may not be observed.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

**UPDATE**

If one do not wish to modify the session on their MySQL environment. One can put below setting to the application properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=5000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The result for the first select is 50. My preference is to solve the issue via spring, JPA mechanisms if possible at all. I really don't want to set session parameter at this point, seems too global to me. It would be better if I could handle this case at the query/transaction level. The solution you proposed will be my last resort though:) Do you know how to set session param in a spring app? Should i use application.properties file?

Comment: There are similar questions related to PESSIMISTIC_WRITE on stackoverflow. The accepted answers say QueryHint works for that case. I have not tested that, though. I started to think that the case with PESSIMISTIC_READ is not implemented by the developers or maybe it is a bug...

Comment: Hi @sanemain - yes you can use `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=5000` on the property file, but if you don't mind can you also share the property/yml file of your application from your question. I am curious on the MySQL dialect you used for jpa. Thanks

Comment: Are you already using this property: `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`? As mentioned from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60368500/11641618) it has something to do with the store engine being used by the MySQL dialect.

Comment: I already checked the other question before asking this question. MySQL dialect i am using is org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect, so that should not be a problem. The property setting you suggested works and I I will use that. Thanks for the help again:)

Comment: Glad it helped you. I will just update the answer to include the property approach. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support query lock timeout and for this reason `@QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "5000") })` is ignored

[image]

For more details: https://blog.mimacom.com/handling-pessimistic-locking-jpa-oracle-mysql-postgresql-derbi-h2/